# animate a centered div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div of unknown width centered in its parent using

```
.centered {
  left : 0px;
  right : 0px;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right : auto;
}
```

It's final style will be

```
.notCentered {
  right : 100%;
  margin-right : 20px;
}
```

I've tried using css3 transitions and the jquery-ui switchClass, but it keeps jerking when it goes from being magically centered to not.

Is there anyway to easily animate this? I know why what I'm doing doesn't work and I want to avoid manually calculating the position in javascript.

my full code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        .container {
          position : absolute;
          width : 400px;
          height : 400px;
          background : blue;
        }

        .centered {
          position : absolute;
          left : 0px;
          right : 0px;
          margin-left : auto;
          margin-right : auto;
          width : 200px;
          height : 200px;
          background : red;
        }

        .notCentered {
          position : absolute;
          right : 100%;
          width : 200px;
          height : 200px;
          background : red;
          -webkit-transition : all 2s ease-in-out;
        }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="centered" onclick="this.className = 'notCentered';"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You've gotta post your code for anybody to see what's going on. or at least a link to the issue.

Comment: please explain what you're trying to accomplish and the problem.

Comment: I would guess manually "centering" via JavaScript upon page load would solve the jerky-ness.

Comment: Basically I have some photos, and I want to slide the current photo out of view each time it progresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Between the two states of a transition you should declare the effective properties that are going to change
2. A transition need be declared in the first state, so it should be in the class `.centered` which is defining the first state of your transition, so try to change like so:

   ```
   /* initial state contaning the transition */         
   .centered {
     position : absolute;
     left  : 0px;
     right : 0px;
     margin-left : auto;
     margin-right : auto;
     width : 200px;
     height : 200px;
     background : red;
     -webkit-transition : all 2s ease-in-out;
   }

   /* final state containing only the property that will change */
   .notCentered {
     right : 100%;
   }
   ```

then add the class (don't make a replacement)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered" onclick="this.className += ' notCentered';"></div>
</div>
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AhvNX/

Comment: did you try this out? This makes the square disappear.

Comment: yes, I simply forgot the js part. The fiddle works on Fx7/Ubuntu

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use JS.

Comment: He said he doesn't want calculate the position in js. Class switching is related to this?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the red square to move all the way against the inner left edge of its parent with a margin on the right side of 20px. This will do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        .container {
          position : absolute;
          width : 400px;
          height : 400px;
          background : blue;
        }

        .centered {
          position : absolute;
          left : 100px;
          right : 0px;
          width : 200px;
          height : 200px;
          background : red;
        }

        .notCentered {
          position : absolute;
          left : 0;
          margin-right: 20px;
          width : 200px;
          height : 200px;
           background : red;
          -webkit-transition : all 2s ease-in-out;
        }


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="centered" onclick="this.className = 'notCentered';"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The problem is that in my actual case I don't know the inner div's width. So I'm forced to use the margin : auto method.

Comment: well the margin auto is centering based on the pixels of its parent and does not give it a definite position to animate from. CSS is using the beginning state, in pixels that is defined, to the ending state that is defined. Since it is not defined in the beginning, the square will jump as it does in you code.

Comment: You can set left to 50% initially, but this still will not put it right in the center. You can't have a percentage and then a pixel position. This seems impossible with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to move the block from right to left.  Use jQuery animate effect here.  You will see the transition happening here.

Give id to your block

```
<div class="centered" id="block">

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#block").animate({right : '400px',},5000);  
 });
</script>
```

As `right:100%` means 400px ( width of parent container )

Comment: the parent container is flexible and not a known width. It must be centered in its parent and animate to the left from there.